# Why does this Netty basic example not work?

Tags: java, udp, netty, nio

I am trying to learn netty to implement a multicast udp server that is able to listen to multiple multicast groups (and potentially in the future multiplex channels that are listening to separate groups) because the Java NIO Selector in Java 8 is not performant enough. I am referring to provided example [here](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/qotm)

Based on that example, I tried writing the following:

```
public class NettyTest implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new NettyTest().run();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();

        b.group(group);
        b.channel(NioDatagramChannel.class);
        b.option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true);
        b.option(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, 1500 * 200);
        b.handler(new MulticastHandler());

        try {
            NetworkInterface nic = NetworkInterface.getByName("eth0");
            ChannelFuture ch = b.bind(new InetSocketAddress(5555));
            NioDatagramChannel ch1 = (NioDatagramChannel) ch.channel();

            ChannelFuture f1 = ch1.joinGroup(new InetSocketAddress("225.1.1.1", 5555), nic).sync();
            ChannelFuture f2 = ch1.joinGroup(new InetSocketAddress("239.1.1.1", 5555), nic).sync();
            ch1.closeFuture().await();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class MulticastHandler extends  SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DatagramPacket> {
    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket msg) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("receive");
    }
}
```

I then ran my Client tester class from my previously implemented project that is using the Java NIO package which would send out messages to the multicast groups. However, it does not do anything. Even though I am not doing anything with the received packets, I still expect it to at least print received upon receiving a packet. What is the error here?

edit: now working

```
public class NettyTest implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new NettyTest().run();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        MulticastHandler handler = new MulticastHandler();
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try{
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByName("eth0");
            b.group(group)
                    .channel(NioDatagramChannel.class)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
                    .option(ChannelOption.IP_MULTICAST_IF, ni)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, 1500 * 200)
                    .handler(new ChannelInitializer<NioDatagramChannel>() {
                @Override
                protected void initChannel(NioDatagramChannel nioDatagramChannel) throws Exception {
                    nioDatagramChannel.pipeline().addLast(handler);
                }
            });

            NioDatagramChannel ch = (NioDatagramChannel)b.bind(5555).sync().channel();
            ch.joinGroup(new InetSocketAddress("239.1.1.1", 5555), ni).sync();
            ch.joinGroup(new InetSocketAddress("225.1.1.1", 5555), ni).sync();
            ch.closeFuture().await();
        } catch (InterruptedException | SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class MulticastHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DatagramPacket>{
    private MoldUdpHeader moldUdpHeader = new MoldUdpHeader();
    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, DatagramPacket datagramPacket) throws Exception {
        System.out.print("read: ");
        moldUdpHeader.decode(datagramPacket.content().nioBuffer(), 0);
        System.out.println(moldUdpHeader.getSeqNum());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you have to add the pipeline to the Channelhandler like follows:

```
class MulticastHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DatagramPacket> {
    private final ChannelPipeline pipeline;

    public MulticastHandler(ChannelPipeline pipeline) {
        this.pipeline = pipeline;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        ctx.pipeline().addLast(pipeline);
        super.channelRegistered(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket msg) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("receive");
    }
}
```

You could also do that outside the cts.pipeline().addLast outside of the method -> in your run method.

Comment: Hey thanks for trying to help, I realised that this wasnt the issue. I revisited some of the other SO posts and tried reading Netty in Action, and I found that while I tried to copy paste then modify a supposed "working" example, I might have removed the sync() on `b.bind(port).sync()`  <--